# Regular expression wrong matches

Tags: regex

I have been using the following regular expression in ASP.NET and Javascript:

```
[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9]{1}[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9_.\-]{2,14}[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9.!]{1}
```

Now, I am migrating to ASP.NET MVC and I am checking my code. 
I find that

```
'test'
%test
```

Are also matches.
That's probably because not the whole string needs to be matched. And the test within 'test' is a valid match.

How do I need to change the RegEx to match the complete string and not only parts of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to match a whole string, use `^` and `$` anchors:

```
^[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9][a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9_.\-]{2,14}[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9.!]$
```

Note: I've also dropped `{1}` since it's completely redundant as a quantifier, by default any character or character class matches only single occurrence. You might also want to shorten your character classes using the case-insensitive modifier. (`/i` in Javascript).

Comment: What is it with all these pointless `{1}` s that have been popping up recently?!? I've think I've seen more in just this past week than in however many years I've used regex for. :S

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9]{1}[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9_.\-]{2,14}[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜß0-9.!]{1}$
```

where `^` matches the beginning and `$` the end of line (text).